# If a fighter can't land during combat, can they land on carriers moved to them during the non-combat move phase?

Tags: axis-and-allies

If I move my fighters into combat and they can't make it back to sea, can I use my non-combat move phase to move my carriers to make it possible for them to land?

I am playing Axis and Allies 1940, 2nd Edition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use your non-combat move phase to have a carrier move to a position so that those planes that were moved in the combat move phase can land. Fighters land in the non-combat move phase of the turn.

When you move fighters in the combat move phase, you can only move them to squares where you can show that it is possible (even if it doesn't end up happening, see below) that they have some way for them to land in the non-combat phase.

Note that providing a landing for your fighters is not optional, it is mandatory. However, it is only required to show it is possible, and not carry out the movement. If the fighters are destroyed, you no longer need to provide a somewhere for them to land, and the carrier can move elsewhere in the non-combat movement phase.